# Using MQTT client in firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mqtt

I have a firebase project (blaze plan) and firestore database.
I need to use mqtt client in cloud functions.

But when I add this line

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
```

to index.js, it can not be deployed to firebase.

It gives this error:

> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
> "status":{"code":3,
>
> "message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},
>
> "authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"*myMail*"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/*myProject*"}

my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

**const mqtt = require('mqtt');**

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
```

Is there any solution to use mqtt package in google cloud functions?

I appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: Just checking, you have followed the instructions for installing dependencies? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies

Comment: thank you for reply @hardillb . 
I had already checked that link. It works if I use that package (escape-html).
But when I add 'mqtt' or 'request' package by npm install command, it does not work.

Comment: And have you followed the instructions in the the included message to look at the function logs?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the MQTT package can be used in cloud functions. Your comments guided me positively.  @hardillb

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I was running the "**npm i mqtt --save**" command in the parent directory of functions.
When it was runned in the ***functions*** directory, it was deployed to firebase without any problem.

as a summary for commands:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
firebase init // select Functions:configure and deploy Cloud Functions 
// it will create a functions directory.
cd functions
npm i mqtt --save
```